# Remote validator issue in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with BootstrapValidator and I am using remote validator for checking that the data is already existing in the database or not.

my php script is called properly and I am able to see that the data exists or not. But the issue is that when i enter new entry, my submit button disabled and focus on the field that I m checking for existing data.

Below is the JQuery Code:

```
$('#form_add_hotel').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        live: 'enabled',
        excluded: [':disabled'],
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {

        $('#form_add_hotel').bootstrapValidator('disableSubmitButtons', false);


},
    fields: {
        hotel_name: {
            //verbose: false,
            validators: {
                stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 20,
                        message: 'The hotel name must be more than 3 and less than 20 characters long'
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The hotel name is required and can\'t be empty'
                },
                 remote: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/Validation-hotel.php',
                    data: function(validator) {
                            return {
                               value: validator.getFieldElements('hotel_name').val()
                            };
                    },
                     message: 'The hotel name already exists'
                }

            }
        }
});
```

I dont knw the reason for disabling the submit button.
Please help to find out the issue??

Comment: Hi, I also faced the same issue but still its not recovered.

Comment: Hi, it seems that no one uses remote validator...